# how to show the aspx design in flex 4.6/how to retrieve the aspx page in to flash buildr 4.6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, flash-builder4.5

In my project we need to retrieve/show the aspx page in flash builder 4.6 and we are trying the code like in mxml application(main page)...

```
          protected function imgtesting_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
      {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    var win:Imageview=PopUpManager.createPopUp(this ,Imageview,true) as   Imageview;              
    win.testobjpckt=this;
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(win);
      }
```

and in title window(popup) the code is like....

```
    <dgFooter:IFrame id="iframe" width="984"
             height="352" autoResize="true"
             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
             overlayDetection="true"
             url="http://localhost/......../Default.aspx"               
                 verticalScrollPolicy="off"/>
```

Here we are able to get the aspx page in to flashbuilder 4.6 and we are able to show the controls of aspx page and those controls are also working and the ISSUE is:
"DESIGN:THE DESIGN OF THE ASPX PAGE IS OVERLAPPING ON THE POPUP(TITLE WINDOW) AND POSITION OF THE CONTROLS ARE ALSO CHANGING IN FLASH BUILDER AND THE ASPX WHOLE PAGE DESIGN IS CHANGING(IN THE SENSE POSITIONS OF CONTROLS ARE CHANGING) SO WE ARE REALLY STRUGGLING A LOT TO GET THE DESIGN IN TO FLASH BUILDER PROPERLY FROM VISUAL STUDIO TO FLASH BUILDER".

SO WE REALLY NEED A SOLUTION TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE.IF ANY HELP I WILL THANKFUL TO THEM A LOT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for the designing,what i did is...
 I just changed the Action-script file for IFRAME by adjusting the x,y coordinates like..

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
 {
   super.commitProperties();

   if(positionChanged)
   {
    var point:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(154,24));
    callJS(methodMove, point.x, point.y);
    positionChanged = false;
   }

   if(sizeChanged)
   {
    callJS(methodResize, width, height);
    sizeChanged = true;
   }
 }
```

so,this makes my issue solved......